# Node.js / Expressjs do not clear session

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, session, express

The application load at the beginning some users via **Angularjs / $http.get()** and on scroll down it load more (infinite scroll).

The page has also some location filters, so users can choose a different Country and City to see Users only from that location.

The controller is this:

```
$scope.country;
$scope.city;
$scope.users = [];
$scope.busy = false;
$scope.destroy = null;

$scope.nextPage = function() {
  if ($scope.busy) return;
  $scope.busy = true;

  $http.get('/users', {
    params: {
      destroy: $scope.destroy,
      country: $scope.country,
      city: $scope.city
    }
  }).success(function(res) {
    var users = res.users;
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      $scope.users.push(users[i]);
    }
    $scope.busy = false;
    $scope.destroy = null;
  }).error(function() {
    alertify.error('Error loading Escorts');
  });
};
```

- On location change I call a service that return new country and city;
- So I set these information and empty the users array;
- I also set the $scope.destroy to tell the server to clear the session;
- In the session I store the ids of the users already loaded in the page to avoid duplications.

This is the code that handle the location change in the same controller:

```
$scope.$on('handleLocationBroadcast', function() {
  $scope.country = SharedLocationService.country;
  $scope.city = SharedLocationService.city;
  $scope.destroy = 'destroy';
  $scope.users = [];
  $scope.nextPage();
});
```

Server side I'm using Expressjs / Node and the controller is pretty simple:

```
exports.getUsers = function(req, res) {
    // If parameter destroy is 'destroy' then clear the session.skip.
    if (req.query.destroy === 'destroy') req.session.skip = [];

    // set skip with session or empty array (need for the first call)
    var skip = req.session.skip || [];

    // set locations (I use to store also the location in a session for future calls
    var country = req.query.country || req.session.country || { $ne: '' };
    var city = req.query.city || req.session.city || { $ne: '' };

    // Get users
    User.find({ '_id' : { '$nin': skip }})
    .where( { 'location.country' : country, 'location.city' : city } )
    .sort({ _id: -1 })
    .limit(15)
    .exec(function(err, users) {

    if (err) res.json({ 'msg': 'Error loading users' });

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        skip.push(users[i]._id);
    }

    req.session.skip = skip;

    res.json({
      users: users
    });

  });
};
```

Everything seems to work very nice and smooth until I change the location.

When I change the location it seems like the session is correctly cleared but as soon as I scroll down to call other Users I see that the session has not been cleared and it result in huge lack of user loading.

So If I'm browsing Users from all cities in United Kingdom and I choose to switch to London only on change location it empty the users array, load 15 users correctly but on scroll down it doesn't load anymore few users that was present in the previous session and looking at the session logs I receive back the entire list.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem by myself doing a `POST` request to clear the session on change location before calling again `$scope.nextPage();`

So basically the code look like:

```
$scope.$on('handleLocationBroadcast', function() {
  $scope.country = SharedLocationService.country;
  $scope.city = SharedLocationService.city;
  $scope.users = [];

  $http({
    url: '/destroy',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { destroy: true }
  }).then(function(res) {
    $scope.nextPage();
  }, function() {
    alertify.error('Error loading users');
  });
}
```

One more request to the server, yes, but it solved the problem now. If there will be a better way to o that I'll be happy to see it and learn something new.